# Writing to a CSV file with formatting with C#

Tags: c#, csv, formatting

I have a my address stored in the database as follows.

Address_1, Address_2, Address_3, City, State, Country, Pin.

In the report (CSV) that is to be generated, all of these should appear under one field Address neatly formatted i.e., as below

Address_1 \n
Address_2 \n
Address_3 \n
City      \n
State     \n
Country   \n
Pin

so that when they open it in Excel, they all appear in one Cell.

How can I get it using C#?

Comment: I guess you want \t as the separator. \n is newline

Comment: @VVS: i guess he tries to create multiline-columns :)

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: Ah, you might be right. Maybe the OP wants to clarify that.

Comment: @VVS: I want the address as a multiline-cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write your CSV file wrapping the address in quotes, it will come out in a single cell in Excel (2010 anyway)... The fields are still separated with a comma, and the `\r\n` indicate the newlines in the file.

```
Tom,"address1,\r\n
address2,\r\n
address3", nextcolumn!\r\n
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm! This method works in Excel 2007 as well (which is what I wanted!)

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I need to import or export data in text form, I use [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/). That said, there are plenty other libraries that are also able to write csv.

Comment: @VVS: Thanks! I cannot use other libraries with this particular client.

Comment: @Kanaini: So if you can't use other libraries, what do you expect from us? To write an RFC 4180 compliant CSV Writer for you?

Comment: @VVS: No, but you can atleast answer as to whether there is a way to do it using C#/Microsoft libraries (and provide helpful pointers) or inform *nay* *educate* me that it cannot be done.

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair:Thanks! So, that means that this sort of thing can never be achieved. Right?

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: I just tested it in Excel 2002 and multiline ex- and import worked for me.

Comment: @Kanini: What did you try for yourself? What's not working? Did you try anything? CSV ist a plain text format, there's no magic here.

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: I'm not Kanini but yes, I did :-)

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: Here's my proof. For the right screenshot I adjusted the row height. http://i52.tinypic.com/14sjq8i.png

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair: The cell height is not adjusted but the data is loaded correctly.

Comment: @VSS: ahhhhh ... eye-opener - THANK YOU!

Comment: @VSS: Yes, the cell height was what was fooling me as well. Thanks for the eye opener though!

Answer (score 0):

CSV format does not allow this feature. CSV format - it just text file that is divided by  some delimiters (e.g. "\t" or "," or ";"). If you want multiline-columns you should use another file format (e.g. XLS)

Comment: Tom's idea just worked. I enclosed the whole address variable in qotes and then put in delimiters of \r\n for each internal sub-field and it worked.